# Riemann Series Theorem

Tags: code-golf, math

The [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) states that the terms of a conditionally convergent series can be permutated such that the resulting series converges to an arbitrary value.

## The Challenge

Write a program or function that takes in three parameters via stdin (or equivalent) or as parameters:

- The expression for the sequence `x_n` (with variable `n`). The exact format (e.g., whether a power is represented as `^`, `pow()` or `**`) is irrelevant and may be chosen to fit your language. Alternatively you may pass a function directly as an argument. The definition of the function does not count towards the byte count.
- A value `S` that we want to approach. Numerical values only are fine, you don't need to support mathematical expressions.
- A threshold `t>0`. Numerical values only are fine here as well.

Your program/function must output (to stdout or equivalent) resp. return a space- or newline-separated list `p_1, ..., p_N` of indices.

Your output must satisfy the condition that the sum from `k = 1..N` over `x_(p_k)` differs from `S` no more than `t` in terms of the absolute difference. In other words, it must satisfy

[image: | sum(1..N, x_(p_k)) - S | <= t]

So far, since the output will be a finite number of indices, the order would not matter. Therefore, another restriction applies: with decreasing threshold `t`, you may only *add* indices to the output (assuming a fixed `S`).

In other words, for a fixed `S`, if `t_1 < t_2` and `[x_1, ..., x_N]` is a solution for `t_2`, then a solution for `t_1` must be of the form `[x_1, ..., x_N, ..., x_M]` with `M >= N`.

## Details and Restrictions

- The order of the arguments may be changed to suit your needs.
- Provide an example call with the arguments from the example below. Ideally, post a link to an online interpreter/compiler.
- `eval` and the like are explicitly allowed for the purpose of evaluating mathematical expressions.
- Sequences are 1-based, so the first index is 1.
- You don't need to take special care of big integers or floating point problems. There will be no extreme test cases such as using machine precision as the threshold.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- You may assume that the sequence passed to your program is conditionally convergent, i.e. that it is possible to solve the task with the given parameters.

## Example

Say your program is in a file `riemann.ext`, then a call might be

```
./riemann.ext "(-1)^(n+1)/n" 0.3465 0.1
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf. The shortest program in bytes (UTF-8 encoding) wins. In case of a tie, the earlier entry wins.

Comment: Why would you penalize answers for supporting expressions? :P

Comment: @Dennis score in code golf is the code length. You want to minimize the score.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Right, and subtracting `-10` adds `10`.

Comment: I shall change the wording. ;) edit: done.

Comment: Is it okay if we require such implementation crud in `x_n` as Javascript's `Math.pow` or Haskell's `fromInteger` for sequences that involve manipulating integers? (as in, assume the expression is eval-ready no matter how non-pseudocodey it is)

Comment: Yes, that was the idea. The challenge should not be to parse expressions.

Comment: If the task isn't to parse an expression, why can't we just input a function and save ourselves 6 characters or more?

Comment: I meant it shouldn't be to parse expressions yourself but have your language tools do it for you. Allowing anything but a string would sort of make it unfair between different languages, imho.

Comment: Namely, Haskell requires quite a bit of extra characters to eval stuff. Namely, it requires an import and it returns a value in the form `IO(Maybe a)`, which requires `fromJust` _and_ an IO action to undo. The former merely requires a bunch of characters, but the latter requires the resulting function to be an IO action (to load the dependencies).

Comment: Nearly every language I can think of supports passing function arguments in some sort. Even C has function pointers (but not `eval`). Even Java has objects (but not `eval`). Even in PHP you can name a global function. Even brainfuck... well... brainfuck doesn't even have `eval`. Allowing function input actually _levels_ the playing field.

Comment: Point taken. You may pass functions. I'll change the description.

Comment: Requiring `eval` is unfair against languages that don't have `eval` (C++, Java...) or languages where `eval` requires quite a few extra bytes (Haskell - also, `eval` is an I/O operation) - and a solution in Assembly would be _awesome_ to see.

Comment: note that your bonus doesn't really make much sense now. You're essentially awarding ten points for two function calls - and Haskell doesn't even distinguish between nullary functions and actual values (though you do have a feature called "polymorphic constants", which do act as nullary functions) - unless you want us to require a function that ignores its sole numeric argument

Comment: You're saying that the program has to be able to find a subset of an infinite set of terms defined by *any* symbolic expression that sums to within *any* arbitrarily small distance of *any* target sum?

Comment: @COTO as long as the symbolic expression represents a conditionally convergent function, yes

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'll upvote any submission that can find a solution for even one symbolic expression and run in less than a fortnight. :D

Comment: @COTO to within which precision?

Comment: @COTO got it. It works like a charm. Now I just need to do basic golfing.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Try `./riemann.ext "(-1)^(n+1)/n" 1e5 1`, or `./riemann.ext "4*(-1)^(n-1)/(2*n-1)" 3.141592653589793238 1e-12`. ;)

Comment: @COTO umm... the harmonic series doesn't grow quite that fast. Remember you have to actually _output_ the indexes.

Comment: @COTO The latter keeps spitting out hundreds of indexes per second, too. At 15000 indexes I'm nearing three digits of precision. And I'm pretty sure a smarter algorithm (fewer indices) would be even slower ;-)

Comment: Well... this will take a while. But you've said "any symbolic expression", and I've got to choose one.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I know. Most conditionally convergent series converge painfully slowly. It's a trivial matter to choose a reasonably low target sum and a reasonably large target precision such that the routine will never converge simply due to the sheer number of terms needed. You can also try something like `./riemann.ext "4*(-1)^(n-1)/(2*n-1)" 1e-4 1e-7` and I suspect the sum would *never* converge.

Comment: I think there should be another restriction: any element of the sequence should, at some point, appear in the sequence for some arbitrary small `t`

Comment: That's a theoretical problem, though. I choose a rather benevolent precision in my tests.

Comment: @proudhaskeller my algorithm satisfies that

Comment: @JanDvorak: I know. ;)  A simple greedy algorithm that picks positive terms as long as the sum is too low, and negative terms as long as the sum is too high, will always find a solution, even if it takes forever. And if the sum contains complex-valued terms... well, you're pooched. :P

Comment: @JanDvorak I meant this should be a part of the restrictions of the challenge as every real permutation satisfies that

Comment: @COTO a simple greedy algorithm is what I'm golfing ;-) Note that the "every term appears eventually" restriction prevents any other solution.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Put 'er in and I'll vote for her. ;)

Comment: @COTO complex values? Umm... They don't seem to be required. Are they?

Comment: Somehow I don't think the Riemann series theorem even works in complex numbers... The harmonic series diverges, the alternating harmonic series converges, yet it's clearly not possible  no hit 0+1i as the limit as the terms are all real.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Absolute value is just the complex modulus in that case. All the same, complex numbers add a whole new dimension of hurt and you're wise to simply ignore them.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not home. Does any answer claim the bonus? If not Jan is right that it makes little sense now and should be removed, but I don't want to upset anyone.

Comment: Two more things: 1) complex numbers can be ignored here, it won't happen. 2) it might be a few days before I can verify submissions correctly, I apologize for that.

Comment: Can we rearrange inputs? I'd like the sequence last.

Comment: Yes, it already says in the details that you are free to chose the order of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python – 88

```python
def R(x,S,t):
 I=[0,0]
 while abs(S)>t:
    i=I[S>0]=I[S>0]+1
    if x(i)*S>0:S-=x(i);print i,
```

`I` stores the indices for positive and negative numbers and to reduce the number of variables, I do not sum up to `0` until I reach `S`, but subtract from `S` until I reach `0`.

I am not entirely sure whether this complies with the restrictions on the input.

The used algorithm should be very nice for a stack-based language.

Comment: So, this adds positive number until it reaches S and then adds negatives until it reaches 0 again? I'm afraid that this doesn't follow the spec

Comment: @proudhaskeller: No. If we forget about the subtraction trick, it either A) adds positive elements until the sum is larger than `S` B) adds negative elements until the sum is smaller than `S`. It alternatingly repeats those steps until the sum is sufficiently close to `S`. The subtraction trick is that instead of going from 0 to `S` by summation, I go from `S` to `0`.

Comment: oh I see. I should be able to use in my code. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>161</s> <s>158</s> 144

because Haskell can deal with infinite lists, instead of doing the parsing stuff this solution receives an infinite list as the sequence.

```
r l s t=unwords[show$[i+1|i<-[0..],l!!i==x]!!0|x<-s%filter(>0)l$filter(<0)l]where(g%j@(p:o))y@(n:b)|abs g<t=[]|g<0=n:((g-n)%j)b|0<1=p:((g-p)%o)y
```

example output:

```
*Main> let harm = zipWith (*) (cycle [1,-1]) (map (1/) [1..]) -- the alternating harmonic numbers
*Main> r harm 3 0.001
"1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99 101 103 105 107 109 111 113 2 115 117 119 121 123 125 127 129 131 133 135 137 139 141 143 145 147 149 151 153 155 157 159 161 163 165 167 169 171 173 175 177 179 181 183 185 187 189 191 193 195 197 199 201 203 205 207 209 211 213 215 217 219 221 223 225 227 229 231 233 235 237 239 241 243 245 247 249 251 253 255 257 259 261 263 265 267 269 271 273 275 277 279 281 283 285 287 289 291 293 295 297 299 301 303 305 307"
```

Comment: Damn it. And I thought my 162-character solution was kinda decent...

Comment: @JanDvorak was yours in Haskell too?

Comment: It was... I'm not done golfing, but don't think I can beat you.

Comment: I think I'm going to steal something...

Comment: @JanDvorak what is it that you are going to steal?

Comment: ... or maybe not. I don't think I can work that into my solution. I am using `partition` in my code instead of a pair of `filter`s.

Comment: The output doesn't look like indices to me since it's not integers. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @IngoBürk oh it's supposed to be a list of indices? I missed that

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be the indices in the order they should be added, separated by a space. Newlines are fine too though. What exactly do you output (out of curiosity)?

Comment: Ah, you output the actual permutated sequence. Gotcha. But it should be the indices instead. I'm sure it's not too hard to fix that :) printing separated by newline instead of whitespace is fine now too if that makes anything easier for you.

Comment: @IngoBurk if anything I would like to return a list or a `[` `]` enclosed comma-seperated list.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. But I think newline separated is a pretty common and sensible output format.

Comment: @IngoBürk Sure then. There isn't really a difference between spaces and newlines (just replace `unwords` with `unlines`).

Answer (score 3):

#### Haskell, 206 characters

```hs
import Data.List
r t e f=unwords.map(show.snd)$(\(x,y:_)->x++[y])$span(\(s,_)->abs(t-s)>e)$m 0$partition(<(0,0))$zip f[1..] where m s(a@((b,c):d),w@((x,y):z))|s<t=(x+s,y):m(x+s)(a,z)|1>0=(b+s,c):m(b+s)(d,w)
```

The sequence itself is an implicit last argument. Usage:

```hs
r 2 0.001 [(-1)**(n+1) / n | n <- [1..]]
```

Beaten before even having been posted, but - oh well. Posted anyways. I also took the liberty of accepting an infinite list as my first argument.

readable version:

```hs
import Data.List
import Debug.Trace
riemannConverge :: (Integral ix, Num v, Ord v, Show ix, Show v) => (ix -> v) -> v -> v -> String
riemannConverge target maxError series = 
    unwords $
    map (show . \(_,ix) -> ix) $
    (\(xs,y:_) -> xs++[y]) $
    span (\(s,_) -> abs (target - s) > maxError) $
    map (\x -> traceShow x x) $
    mergeNP 0 $
    partition (\(x,_) -> x<0) $
    zip series [1..]
  where
    mergeNP s (nss@((nVal,nIx):ns), pss@((pVal,pIx):ps))
     | s < target = (pVal + s, pIx) : mergeNP (pVal + s) (nss,ps)
     | otherwise  = (nVal + s, nIx) : mergeNP (nVal + s) (ns,pss)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Haskell. Does this print the list of indices? Just asking since the other Haskell solution doesn't.

Comment: It does. That's what the `map snd $ ... $ zipWith [1..]` is for.

Comment: Do you require a string instead of a list of numbers?

Comment: If Haskell automatically prints a list of numbers in the correct format (space or newline separated)  without further modification then it's okay.

Comment: @IngoBürk GHCi produces a comma-separated list. Buh oh well... here we go.

Comment: @archaeophyrryx can we meet in a chat room? Please invite me.